# How to read an ArrayList from internal storage

Tags: java, android, arraylist, internal-storage

I have an ArrayList which has about 1000 contacts details. It takes 30 seconds to open.
So I store this list in internal storage of android. I check details of app after installing its data shows 16 kb, which was previously 0. So data is being stored but when I try to read data from list,the app is closed with nullpointerexception.

**My main class is**:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //Remove notification bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listcontact = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.listapp);
    ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    listcontact.setEmptyView(img);
    try {
        aa = readFromInternalStorage();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(aa.isEmpty()){
        getnumber(this.getContentResolver());
    }
    else{
        adapt=new ContactAdapter(MainActivity.this, aa);
        listcontact.setAdapter(adapt);
    }
    edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_search);
    edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //MainActivity.this.adapt.getFilter().filter(s);
            int textlength = cs.length();
               ArrayList<ContactStock> tempArrayList = new ArrayList<ContactStock>();
               for(ContactStock c: aa){
                   String srch= c.getNumber().replaceAll(" ", "");
                  if (textlength <= c.getName().length() || textlength <= srch.length()) { 
                     if (c.getName().toLowerCase().contains(cs.toString().toLowerCase()) || srch.toLowerCase().contains(cs.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        tempArrayList.add(c);
                     }
                  }
               }
               adapt = new ContactAdapter(MainActivity.this, tempArrayList);
               listcontact.setAdapter(adapt);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

class Info {
      public String name;
      public String phone;
      public String picture;

      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return name + " " + phone;
      } 
    }
public void getnumber(ContentResolver cr) {
    Cursor phone = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    while (phone.moveToNext()) {
        Info info = new Info();
        ids=phone.getInt(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_ID));
        info.phone=phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        info.name=phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        long id=Long.valueOf(ids);
        byte[] imagearray = queryContactImage(ids);
        System.out.println("...........name");
        aa.add(new ContactStock(info.name,info.phone,imagearray));
    }
    saveToInternalStorage(aa);
    phone.close();
    adapt=new ContactAdapter(MainActivity.this, aa);
    listcontact.setAdapter(adapt);
}


private byte[] queryContactImage(int imageDataRow) {
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO
    }, ContactsContract.Data._ID + "=?", new String[] {
        Integer.toString(imageDataRow)
    }, null);
    byte[] imageBytes = null;
    if (c != null) {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            imageBytes = c.getBlob(0);
        }
        c.close();
    }
    return imageBytes;
}

public void saveToInternalStorage(ArrayList<ContactStock> aList) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream of = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        of.writeObject(aList);
        of.flush();
        of.close();
        fos.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("InternalStorage", e.getMessage());
    }
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ArrayList<ContactStock> readFromInternalStorage() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    ArrayList<ContactStock> toReturn = null;
    FileInputStream fis;
    try {
        fis = openFileInput(NAME);
        ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        toReturn = (ArrayList<ContactStock>) oi.readObject();
        oi.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("InternalStorage", e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("InternalStorage", e.getMessage()); 
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

### Update :-

my stacktrace is
[image]

errors in logcat

```
03-11 12:47:52.037: E/InternalStorage(2919): Read an exception; java.io.NotSerializableException: com.webshine.quickdialplus.ContactStock
03-11 12:47:52.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2919): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 12:47:52.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2919): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.webshine.quickdialerwidget/com.webshine.quickdialplus.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 12:47:52.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2919):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
03-11 12:47:52.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2919):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
03-11 12:47:52.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2919):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
03-11 12:47:52.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2919):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
03-11 12:47:52.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2919):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
03-11 12:47:52.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2919):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
03-11 12:47:52.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2919):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
03-11 12:47:52.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2919):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 12:47:52.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2919):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-11 12:47:52.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2919):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
03-11 12:47:52.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2919):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-11 12:47:52.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2919):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-11 12:47:52.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2919): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 12:47:52.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2919):     at com.webshine.quickdialplus.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62)
03-11 12:47:52.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2919):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
03-11 12:47:52.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2919):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
03-11 12:47:52.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2919):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
03-11 12:47:52.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2919):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: use lazyloading of the contacts when you are going to list in a listview.

Comment: share the crash logs.

Comment: @Shriram I see many other apps like this(contact+) they store details in their data when install and read from data whenever app is opened.

Comment: @TinkuRana post the stacktrace not screenshot. extract the exception part from the logcat and paste it here

Comment: @TinkuRana What is line 62 `MainActivity.java`?

Comment: @Raghunandan I have added my full main activity in question line 62 is if(aa.isEmpty()){

Comment: @TinkuRana aa is null. check it

Comment: @Raghunandan aa is null, it means readFromInternalStorage() is not working. can you take a look at this method it is in last of code posted above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49452/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-tinku-rana)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let your serialised class be serializable

```
   Class ContactStock implements Serializable
    {
         // your existing code
    }
```

Comment: Not serialize Exception from ContactStock

Comment: have you implemented the interface and cleaned the files? also try to replace  ArrayList<ContactStock> toReturn = null; with ArrayList<ContactStock> toReturn = new ArrayList<ContactStock>(); to avoid side effects.

Comment: Ya Mem thanks for answering, I remove this exception by  implemented the interface on contact adapter class also. but now it is taking 2 3 seconds to open. is there any method to improve the performance.

Comment: when you've alot of entrys in the list, you coul'd initial the array list with a bigger capacity (new ArayList<ContactStock>(1000) ) or you can use a linked list. - But remember you do a read on a sd card, so this is expensive.

Comment: what if i don't know size of arraylist ?

Comment: difficult to say, i'll use the average guessed size or linked list.